# deleting JSON array element in PHP, and re-encoding as JSON

Tags: php, json

```
function deleteNews($selected) {
    $file = file_get_contents('news.json', true);

    $data=json_decode($file,true);
    unset($file);

foreach($selected as $index){
 unset($data[$index]);
 }


  $result=json_encode($data);

  file_put_contents('news.json', $result);
    echo $result;
    unset($result);
    $url="./deleteNews.php";
   //redirect($url);
    }
```

The above function is supposed to delete an entry from a JSON like :

```
[
     {
           "dummy":"dummy",
           "dummy1":"dumy"
      },
      {
           "dummy":"dummy1",
           "dummy1":"dummy"
      }
]
```

But in the end the function inserts numerical indexes in the JSON, which is not desirable.

The result is like

```
[
    "0":
       {
          "dummy":"dummy",
          "dummy1":"dumy"
       },
     "1":
       {
           "dummy":"dummy1",
           "dummy1":"dummy"
       }
 ]
```

How can I get my original JSON format from this? I don't want that 0 1 2 index part.

N.B: it's the `foreach` that does this. Without the `foreach`, the JSON is created as expected.

Comment: You're omitting something from your question. The result you refer to is caused by the presence of a **non-numeric** key. Is unsetting a numeric index the **only** thing you do? I suspect not. If I try doing this, I get a correct JSON. Try posting the exact wrong JSON you get. I bet there's a text key at the lowest level in there somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, the exact json contains non-numeric key, the keys are: "newsHead" and "newsDetail" in place of dummy and dummy1, but I don't understand what you are implying...

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. The real problem in the output you posted is that the actual indices are not 0 and 1, but more probably 1 and 2 or 0 and 2. See my not-answer for the sordid details :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it with array_values:

```
$result = json_encode(array_values($data));
```

Comment: That *might* work -- but, if it does, it's actually *hiding a bug*. I'd advise against, until a proper understanding of what's going on is achieved.

Comment: lserni has a point though. Unsetting indices obviously upsets the underlying structures. Maybe you could splice the array or somesuch, not unset.

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR** PHP arrays with *all numerical keys*, *starting at zero*, *sorted* and *without holes* are the only kind that will get rendered into a JSON array `[ "square", "brackets" ]`. All other kinds will become JSON dictionaries `{ "curly": "brackets" }`.

---

The reason for the behaviour you observe, and the reason why `array_values` appears to fix the problem (and in *this* case, actually *does*), is in the difference between PHP and JSON arrays and dictionaries.

This is a PHP array with contiguous numerical keys:

```
$a = array( "Apple", "Banana", "Canteloupe" );
```

This is really

```
$a = array( 0 => "Apple", 1 => "Banana", 2 => "Canteloupe" );
```

In JSON this becomes an **array**:

```
[ "Apple", "Banana", "Canteloupe" ]
```

This instead is a PHP array with text keys (hash):

```
$a = array( "a" => "Apple", "b" => "Banana", "c" => "Canteloupe" );
```

In JSON this is a **dictionary** (note the curly braces):

```
{ "a": "Apple", "b": "Banana", "c": "Canteloupe" }
```

**Some operations change a PHP-array-rendered-as-array (ARA) to a -rendered-as-dictionary (ARD)**.

And these operations are:

- Adding a TEXT key to a NUMERIC array.
- Having numeric keys NOT in uninterrupted **sorted** sequence 0...N.

So these **seem** to be arrays, but are actually **dictionaries**:

```
$a = array ( 2 => "Canteloupe", 1 => "Banana", 0 => "Apple" );

$a = array ( 0 => "Apple", 2 => "Canteloupe" );

$a = array ( 1 => "Banana", 0 => "Apple" );
```

And this finally is the reason why deleting a key **that is not the last one** will thrash your array and make it a dictionary:

```
0 1 2 3 => remove 3 => 0 1 2 => still an array!
0 1 2 3 => remove 2 => 0 1 3 => NOT an array!
0 1 2 3 => remove 2 => 0 1 3 => not an array => remove 3 => 0 1 => again an array!
```

If you were to subject the array to any renumbering operation, or to `array_values`, you would get a purely numerical array again:

```
/**
* delete news items given their index.
*
* @param array $selected     the list of indexes (e.g. [ 0, 1, 7 ])
* @return nothing
*/

function deleteNews(array $selected = [ ]) {
    try {
        $news = array_values( // Reorder...
            array_diff_key( // ...all keys...
                json_decode(file_get_contents('news.json', true), true), // ...in here...
                array_flip($selected) // ...that are not in $selected.
            )
        );
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // TODO handle errors (e.g. file not found and bad JSON)
    }
    try {
        file_put_contents('news.json', json_encode($news));
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // TODO handle errors
    }
    // $url="./deleteNews.php";
    // redirect($url);
}
```

So if your code had removed the *last* indexes of your array, things would have *appeared* to be working. As soon as the unsetting created a hole in the array, or a text key was added...

Same goes for **sorting**: `[ 1 => "B", 0 => "A" ]` is a JSON dictionary. Sort it preserving key associations to `[ 0 => "A", 1 => "B" ]`, and it becomes a JSON array.

One thing to note about your code: you read "news.json" with include-path set to *true*. But then you save it into the current directory. If you have "news.json" anywhere else in your path except in the current directory, you will end up having *two* news.json files; which of the two is then used depends on the include path itself.

## Local files and security

Saving local files, as it happens here with `news.json`, is okay, but some precautions are often in order.

In general it's best to place such "variable" files in a directory of their own (e.g. "./cache" or "./temp") with a suitable `.htaccess` to prevent direct reading/execution unless it's needed, and so that permissions may be enforced more clearly.

For example one could use a "./data" directory, and have the PHP files **everywhere else** set to read-only for the web server; and finally instruct, say, the Apache Web server so that this one directory, while writeable by the web server, could not be easily used for exploiting the system:

```
<directory "/var/www/mysite/htdocs/data">
    # You CANNOT ask for /data and have a directory listing. Just in case.
    options      -Indexes
    # You CANNOT save "news.php" and have it executed :-)
    php_flag     engine     off
</directory>
```

This way, even if someone succeeeded in uploading a file on your system and that file contained executable, malicious PHP code, that code would not be allowed to execute (not directly, at least).

## More on security: real-life experience

Allowing direct access to files under the control of a third party, even indirectly, is **always** potentially dangerous - to **others** if not to you. For example, storing a JSON object with information gathered on a third site. I've just completed a successful attack test on a client's website. *Mutatis mutandis*,

- I set up a page on my own web site with crafted data.
- I logged in on WWW.CLIENT with my account (OK, so I left traces...)
- I directed WWW.CLIENT to access EVIL.COM and get the data
- From my own account I could see what was then rendered on WWW.CLIENT depending on escape codes, malformed UTF8 characters and other tricks
- In the end (1) I was able to inject the command to load a CDN-like Javascript file (residing on EVIL.COM) and have it execute (2) in the security context of WWW.CLIENT
- After several more machinations, I was able to direct a customer of WWW.CLIENT (still me with a test account, of course) to a crafted link on WWW.CLIENT that would silently supply EVIL.COM with the customer's authentication tokens (3), (4) allowing (e.g.) to modify extant orders by removing his merchandise, adding my own, and changing the delivery address (5).

This exploited a total of five security flaws (for example 4: the authentication token was not linked to the owner's IP address, or was not regenerated at each transaction, and 5: changes to invoicing or delivery did not trigger a request to re-enter the credit card information). While you might think that such security flaws were, well, security flaws, and the client was unaware of them, they actually were **known features, there by design**, in the name of "usability" and "user convenience". Flaw 2 stems from an evil-counseled use of `eval()` in an ancillary library which isn't like to change anytime soon. In the end, changing local data storage capability (flaw 1) is likely to be the **only** intervention I'll be able to realistically sell to this particular customer.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate explanation, anyway, I am replacing the same news.json in the current directory, so it's okay...

And as you have suspected, I am deleting an element from the middle of the JSON array....

Comment: If that's the case, you should remove that ', true' from `file_get_contents`... just in case. I'm adding a footnote to my already lengthy answer :-D

Answer (score 0):

function deleteNews($selected) {
    $file = file_get_contents('news.json', true);

```
$data=json_decode($file,true);
unset($file);

foreach($selected as $index){
  unset($data[$index]);
}

foreach($data as $value){
  $new_data[] = $value;
}

$result=json_encode($new_data);

file_put_contents('news.json', $result);
echo $result;
unset($result);
$url="./deleteNews.php";
```

//redirect($url);
 }

Comment: This will work - apart from `$new_data` not being defined - but it's the same thing as calling `array_values`...