# Laravel Session::forget Method alters my JSON Get Request Output

Tags: angularjs, json, laravel, session, laravel-5

**Update:**

I think the problem occurs because the last key number can be deleted from the Session Array but when I don't delete the last key number i get the different format. Not sure how to solve this yet.

---

I'm currently storing and retrieving data through angular requests
 that puts and retrieves values from a Laravel Session Array.

```
// Code for pushing into Laravel Session Array
Session::push('cart', $object); 

// Code for retrieving data into Laravel Session Array
return Session::get('cart');
```

Now i'm using a foreach loop to update quantity or where this question
 is about: To remove an object from the Laravel Session Array Cart when
quantity is 0.

```
public function updateQuantity($id, $quantity, $operator){
    $cart = Session::get('cart', []);

    foreach ($cart as $index => &$product) {
        if ($product['id'] == $id) {
            if($operator == '+'){
                $product['quantity'] = $product['quantity'] + $quantity;
            } else if($operator == '-'){
                $product['quantity'] = $product['quantity'] - $quantity;
                if($product['quantity'] == 0){
                    Session::forget('cart.' . $index);
                    $cart = Session::get('cart', []);
                    Session::push('cart', $cart);
                }
            }
            Session::set('cart', $cart);
            $this->new_product = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $this->new_product;
}
```

**This part of the code above is altering my JSON output:**

```
Session::forget('cart.' . $index);
$cart = Session::get('cart', []);
Session::push('cart', $cart);
```

**JSON Situation Before Deleting:**

```
[
  {
   "id":293,
   "quantity":2
  },
  {
   "id":294,
   "quantity":2
  }
]
```

**JSON Situation After Deleting:**

```
{"1":{"id":293,
      "quantity":2}
}
```

**But Should Be:**

```
[
  {
   "id":293,
   "quantity":2
  }
]
```

This is my Angular Get Request which simply calls: `return Session::get('cart')`

```
Cart.getCart()
   .then(function (success){
       $scope.cart = success.data;
    }).catch(function (e){
       console.log("got an error in the process", e);
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated. Not sure what is causing my json array to transform into a different data model.

*Additional Note: when I add the last object in the Session and delete the same object again it works as intended. When I'm switching the delete order it messes up the json.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Better Solution:**

Got the theory behind this from another stackoverflow article:
[deleting JSON array element in PHP, and re-encoding as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27087974/deleting-json-array-element-in-php-and-re-encoding-as-json)

**Code adjustments here:**

```
Session::forget('cart.' . $index);
$cart = Session::get('cart', []);
Session::push('cart', $cart);
```

**Will be:**

```
Session::forget('cart.' . $index);
Session::get('cart', []);
return null;
```

**Get Session Cart Value**

```
return json_encode(array_values(Session::get('cart')));
```

Only thing that was required was to make use of `array_values`. This will renumber the json array.

---

**Old Solution:**

Solved the problem by replacing the following:

```
Session::forget('cart.' . $index);
$cart = Session::get('cart', []);
Session::push('cart', $cart);
```

Put the code below as replacement:

```
Session::forget('cart.' . $index);
$temp_cart = Session::get('cart', []);
Session::forget('cart');
foreach($temp_cart as $c){
   Session::push('cart', $c);
}
return null;
```

Don't think it's the best solution as i'm rebuilding the whole Session Array so any ideas would be welcome.