# Can't Delete Specific Keys and Values from JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to delete specific key and value pair from external JSON file in PHP when user clicked delete button on the page.

I'm not familiar with PHP so I couldn't able to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I looked at more than 20 questions on stackoverflow but none of them helped to solve my problem.

What I'm trying to achieve in general to write a simple script which user can write something in textbox and submit, show it on the page and when user wants delete it. (I have done the submit and showing part but stuck on deleting part)

**Firstly my JSON file:**

```
{
"departman1":
[
{"departman1stage":"John"},
{"departman1stage":"Test"},
{"departman1stage":"Test2"}
]
}
```

***Part of my index.php file:***

```
    ...
    include ('yazdir.php');
    include ('sil.php');
    <div class='icerik'>
                    
    
                    <?php
                    
                    foreach ($json['departman1'] AS $d){
                        echo '<p class="' . $d['departman1stage'] .'">';
                        echo "--> ";
                        echo $d['departman1stage'];
                        echo '<form action="sil.php" method="POST"><button type="submit" class="dugme" name="' . $d['departman1stage'] .'"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></form>';
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "</p>";
                    }
                    ?>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <form action="yazdir.php" method="POST">
                    <div class="icerik"><p><input type="text" name="departman1stage"></p></div>
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Gonder">
                    </form>
...
```

***It is not related with problem but I still put my yazdir.php code:***

```
$json_sifreli = file_get_contents ("data.json");
$json = json_decode($json_sifreli, true);
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
     $data = array(
        'departman1stage'          => $_POST["departman1stage"]
           );
       array_push ( $json['departman1'], $data );
        $json_sifreleme = json_encode($json, true);
       file_put_contents('data.json', $json_sifreleme);
}
```

sil.php is currently blank, as I said I tried different methods. Some of them deleted whole JSON file and put 'null' into it. Some of them deleted unrelated key and value pair. As a last resort, I decided to write here.

Thanks in advance, sorry for taking your time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete element from json with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18213026/delete-element-from-json-with-php)

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones Hi, I saw and tried that answer by customizing it to me case. But it didn't work for me. No matter what GET value I gave, it deletes the first key value pair and deletes the array brackets.

Comment: I linked to that question because it explains how to delete keys using `unset`, which your code doesn't appear to do at all.

Comment: I think this question would be better if you posted the code that relates to the deletion part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete keys using the PHP built-in [unset function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php). It works on individual array keys:

```
<?php
$foo = [
    'a' => 23,
    'b' => 42,
];
unset($foo['a']);
var_dump($foo);
```

Results in:

```
array(1) {
  ["b"]=>
  int(42)
}
```

PHP arrays are hash maps, no matter if keys are strings are numeric. In your example JSON, `departman1` is an array with numeric keys. You can delete numeric keys with `unset` as well:

```
$bar = [
    23,
    42,
];
unset($bar[0]);
var_dump($bar);
```

Results in:

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  int(42)
}
```

Note that the dump shows `1` as key. Unsetting numeric keys does not cause the array to be renumbered. You end up with holes and this will show up in `json_encode` output:

```
echo json_encode($bar);
// Results in: {"1":42}
```

So you *could* go through the swamp of using a JSON file as data store, but be cautioned it's a Pandoras Box full of hardships. It also doesn't scale beyond one concurrent user because `json_encode` and `json_decode` do not provide [ACID properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID), which database management systems provide you. My suggestion: ditch the JSON file and pick up a proper database such as PostgreSQL or MySQL (they have good support in PHP via [PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)).

[view the example code in playground](https://www.tehplayground.com/iAqq2FYDrIWZ6FTu)

(BTW: You are using the `$_POST` variable directly, which is unsafe user input. Sanitizing input can be done with PHP built-in [filter_var function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php).)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Great first answer, hope to see more